# Onboard 1.4 crashes X.org on Arch Linux

Tags: xorg, keyboard, unicode, crash

Recently, a problem arose, which I suspect of being a bug, but I am not sure. I use Onboard virtual keyboard on my tablet PC powered by Arch Linux. It works nicely, but one thing is not working well.

If you use "Small" layout, you can see there are Symbols and "Emojis" tab. Both that groups are encoded in Unicode, of course, but there the strange thing happens. When you type ANY character that is not part of ASCII, it crashes, and restarts Xorg (together with lightdm).

Journal (systemd-journald) has nothing relevant about the crash. If I redirect the stderr to file, it shows only `Gdk-CRITICAL: assertion error ...` but that doesn't seem like the cause.

Then, next line reports Xorg error 11 resource temporarily unavailable. When I read Xorg.0.log.old, it showed quite irrelevant backtrace (because only libc and xorg binaries were referenced) and the last line reported segfault. What could be the cause of this symptome?

I have `ttf-dejavu` and `ttf-droid` installed, and it displays the symbols correctly on the virtual keyboard, but it simply cannot write them.

What is causing this?  How can I fix it?